# Second order ODE - solve it given two particular solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(3x^2+x)y'' + 2y' - 6xy = 4-12x^2$$

Where

$$y_1 = 2x$$
$$y_2 = (x+1)^2$$

Are two particular solutions that are already given. Now I know that the solution should be $$y = C_1y_1 + C_2y_2$$

I'm confused now. I have two methods in my mind, and I'd appreciate if someone could tell me which is the correct way to proceed

1. I put $f(x) = 0$, i.e. $(3x^2+x)y'' + 2y' - 6xy = 0$, solve to get the solution of the homogenous equation ($y_h$) and add it to $y = C_1y_1 + C_2y_2$
2. I put $y = C_1y_1 + C_2y_2$, and use variation of parameters to find functions $C_1$ and $C_2$, and substitute them in $y = C_1y_1 + C_2y_2$

The reason why I'm confused is if I am given one solution, I'd use reduction of order to find the second one, after which I would use variation of parameters to find the particular solution.

Comment: $y_1$ is the particular solution not a solution to the homogeneous DE...You can use $y_2$ and reduction of order to solve the homogeneous equation

Comment: @MtGlasser I am confused by the wording of the exercise, it says that both $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two particular solutions of the equation

Comment: is it $3x^2$  or $3x^3$  that factors $y''$ ? It should be  $$(3x^3+x)y'' + 2y' - 6xy = 4-12x^2$$

Comment: @MtGlasser It's $3x^2$! Why?

Comment: Because for $3x^2$ a solution is $x^2+1$  so that $c(x^2+1)$ is a soltion ....And $y_2=x^2+1 +2x=x^2+1+y_p$

Answer (score 1):

$$(\color{red}{3x^3}+x)y'' + 2y' - 6xy = 4-12x^2$$
For this DE $y_1=2x$ is a particular solution.

And
$$y_2=(x+1)^2=x^2+1+y_1=x^2+1+y_p$$
Is another particular solution since it's the sum of a particular solution and the homogeneous solution:
$$y=C(x^2+1)$$
This solves the DE I posted. And  the complete solution is:
$$y=C(x^2+1)+\dfrac Bx+2x$$
So maybe there is a mistake in the DE you posted.

Comment: Thanks! Are you active on chat?

Comment: You're welcome. Not really but if you post question here and i can answer I will  answer @l0ner9

Comment: What confuses is this   A particular solution can also be made by additon of the homogeneous solution and the particular solution....This is the point.  @l0ner9

Comment: Oh okay. I just wanted to inquire if you'd be here on thursday around 12:45pm your time since I will be preparing for a big exam on friday and I may have a question or two.

That's what I'm talking about! I just talked to my professor who said that there indeed can be a mistake in the ODE ($x^3$), but the particular solution thing still confuses me

Comment: I see  well you can always post questions  people here are really want to help..... For the particular solution you have to know that any sum made with a particular solution and a homogeneous solution is still a particular solution...For example $x^2+1$ solve the homogeneous DE I posted and $2x$ is a particular solution then $2(x^2+1)+2x$ is also a particular solution and so is $3(x^2+1)+2x$  @l0ner9